# Узнать тип данных столбца в SQLite под Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Я парсю несколько `EditText` каждая отвечает за колонку.

После этого, собираю из них запрос на вставку в БД.

Но проблема в том, что `VARCHAR` нужно брать в кавычки.
Как программно определить тип колонки из курсора ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.getType(i);
```

Возвращает int:

> Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL
>
> Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER
>
> Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT
>
> Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING
>
> Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB